# In theory, Is it possible irradiate a blob of matter -for instance- with microwaves in order to that matter emit more energy than has received?

Tags: thermal-radiation, microwaves

Suppose that you want coerce a block of matter to lose his energy. I mean thermal energy. This should be done by irradiation of more energy. The final thermal energy should be lower that the original thermal energy - for instance with microwaves or infrared or something that currently I don't know -

In theory, Is it posible?

Each atom/molecule will always gain energy?

Comment: It's not possible the way I believe you imagine it (your question isn't very precise), but something similar happens in stimulated emission, which is the effect behind the laser. One could think about exothermal chemical reactions that start after being initiated by heat or compression (fire, explosives), which also satisfy your criteria somewhat, but all of these are either one time processes or there has to be an external energy source (as in a laser) that keeps supplying energy to the system.

Comment: There is something called a pulse tube refrigerator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_tube_refrigerator. One can also cool atoms with light (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling), but that requires very special circumstances where the atoms are extremely cold, already. Particle beams in an accelerator can also be cooled, that's called stochastic cooling, and requires very special circumstances, again: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_cooling. Microwave and chicken thighs... that won't work, but it's a good question, though!

Comment: @CuriousOne i will read these links, Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A block of matter in warm surroundings is always exchanging energy with its surroundings. Partly by conduction and partly by radiation. Radiation is important when things are hot. If the block of matter is hotter than its surroundings, it will emit more radiation than it receives. This will cool the block and heat the surroundings until they are the same temperature.